# Java+Reflection: Invoke method on variable access. Is it possible?

Tags: java, reflection, properties

I was wondering if it is possible, using reflection, or something similar to invoke a method whenever a variable is accessed in read or write mode. In a nutshell my goal is similar to the behavior of C# properties.

Example: Let's say I have a two classes A and B...

```
public class A{
    public int field;

    public void foo(){ System.out.println("Field modified");}
}

public class B{
    public void bar(A a){
        a.field = 1;
    }
}
```

...and I want to execute the method A.foo() whenever a.field is written.

Is this achieveable in Java?

Thanks in advance

p.s. I'm aware that good programming practices suggest to use getter and setter. I just need to know if what I want to do is feasible.

ac

Comment: C# properties are syntactic sugar for the getter and setter.

Comment: I'm aware they are syntactic sugars, but think about the scenario in which you need to test/debug a code written by someone else and you want to track how a variable is accessed. In C# you can workaround the problem transforming the variable of the class into a property, keeping the rest of the code intact. The compiler would take care of everything

Comment: If you are testing someone's code can you get a copy of the source and modify it. or decompile the code first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not via reflection - reflection simply lets you get access to static information about classes/fields/etc at runtime.

[Aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is more what you're thinking of - this lets you inject small bits of code (called "advice") at certain points of your source code (such as before a method runs, when a field is set, etc.).  This would almost certainly let you do what you are looking for.

A word of warning though - as you seemed to pick up, it's unlikely to be a good idea to rely on aspects for your general logic as it's very hard to reason with them, and work out exactly what will happen when (by definition, they break the default mental model that calling a method foo() means that control passes directly to that method).  AOP is **great** for things like logging or debugging though, as it lets you write small bits of code that affect a lot of cross-cutting concerns with little effort, and don't require you to modify the code of the underlying application.  Your advice can be weaved in as required, and simply left out when not required.

Comment: Do you know of any aspect oriented library/extension that would allow you to do this for java? I thought aspects only talked about method-invocations / returns etc...

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. I needed a way to "decorate" a variable access with some code and I couldn't use getter/setter (or at least it was not the best solution. Thank you Andrzej

Comment: @aioobe: [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) offers `get` and `set` join points that can be used in pointcuts to detect field-level access.

Comment: nice! I had no idea about that.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if it is possible, using reflection, or something similar to invoke a method whenever a variable is accessed in read or write mode.

Yes. If you properly encapsulate your data using getter and setter methods, you could put such code in these methods, or, override these methods in a subclass.

(now I saw your ps) - No, there is no way of solving this using reflection. If I was asked (forced?) to solve this problem, I would write my own class loader, perhaps using the [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) framework, and replace each get-field/set-field instructions with proper calls to getter/setter methods.

They actually have a FAQ-entry for this, with a solution:

- [9. How do I generate Setters and Getters for my class?](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q9)

Comment: This is more "hardcore" than I thought but it's a good alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do it in Java. As you said, use getters and setters.